# Setting a UITableViewCell backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView are not working in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Setting backgroundView and selectedBackgroundView in any of the following methods does not seem to work.

```
UIView * bSg = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView * bg = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIImageView *topSImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgActive"]];
UIImageView *topImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
[bg addSubview:topImage];
[bSg addSubview:topSImage];
self.backgroundView = bg;
self.selectedBackgroundView = bSg;
```

Have tried setting in all these cell methods

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
- (id)init
```

When put in `layoutSubviews` it works when first loaded, but when selecting a cell nothing happens (aka the selectedBackgroundView isn't set).

And yes I have set `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` in layoutSubviews to clear the iOS7 white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, the backgrounds get automatically set and you have to reset them in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: So the problem was this tableview class inherits from a class that sets its cells via a class method (+). Then my tableview wasn't even using the cellForRowAtIndex method, not sure why they built it this way. After hours of sifting through code I found the cellForRowAtIndex that was being called, up the heirarchy, and altered it. The following needed implemented as well (cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code to set background image for cell in table view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  ...
  //set cell background
  UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shopsCellBackground"]];
  background.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  background.opaque = NO;
  cell.backgroundView = background;
  ...
}
```

I believe the key thing for you is to set background image and selected background image for cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath table view method not inside your cell class.